# Bootstrap div as multiline in yii2

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a list in bootstrap css and its responsive which is good but i am making a notification list with long text just like notification in facebook

I have one question that how can i make that div multiline
like look at the image below.

I want to make that `div` as if like if i resize the window than it should automatically break the text and display in the next line.

And here is the `html` of that `li`

```
<li>'+
   '<div id="notification-panel" class="panel panel-default">'+
     '<div id="notification-body" class="panel-body">'+
        '<div id="notification-image" class="panel-more1">'+
          '<img src="../uploads/'+notificationlist[index].image+'" class="img-rounded" width="50" height="50" />'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div id="notification-info" class="panel-info">'+
          '<label> Someone just checked into '+ notificationlist[index].sourceName + '</label><br>'+
       '</div>'+
    '</div>'+
  '</div>'+
'</li>
```

And here is the css which possibly affects that i tried to change

```
#notification-body{
  font-size:12px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#notification-panel{
  margin-bottom:5px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#notification-info{
  margin: 0px;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

[image]

Comment: put `word-wrap` property to your `div` like `word-wrap:breakword`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao that is a statement and not a single long word.. thats why i guess its not working and i already tried what you suggested

Comment: Do your divs have bootstrap column size classes like col-md-3 or col-sm-3?

Comment: @TaylorH. No i am not using grid system... i did update the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok somehow i got the answer

All i had to do was to change the `width` of that div so that when ever i resize the window it will force to break the sentence and break it to next size.